# Entity Framework post decimal to int field

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I am using Entity Framework 6 in an ASP.NET MVC application. I have a field in the model `int Time` and I post from the client Time = 2.3. The modelState is invalid but without any error. How can I validate this to throw a useful error to the user?

Comment: If the modelstate is invalid, you are validating it.  Show us your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery.validate.js then the form dont even post the info to the post action. This javascript code makes the browser shows a validation error and dont submit the form. However, you can always check the validation yourself if the form submits in the action, like this:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Test(YourModelClass vo)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                int time;
                if (!int.TryParse(Request.Form["Time"].ToString(), out value))
                    ModelState.AddModelError("Time", "The Test field should be a number");
                return View(vo);
            }

            //do something here with your vo
            return View();
        }
```